# AngularJS - Directive row by row in a table

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a table generetad via PHP while and handled by AngularJS:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Col 1</th>
     <th>Col 2</th>
     <th>Col 3</th>
   </tr>


   <?php
      while(...){
   ?>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input type="text" ng-model="calcolo.ore">
          </td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" ng-model="calcolo.ricavo">
          </td>
          <td>
             <input type="text" ng-model="calcolo.abbatt">
          </td>
          <td>
             <input type='text'  ng-show="calcolo.abbatt" value='{{netti() | currency:"&euro;"}}'>
          </td>

       </tr>

   <?php } ?>
```

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ng-currency'])
    .controller("userController",
        function($scope) {

             $scope.fattlord = function() {
                return ($scope.calcolo.ore * $scope.calcolo.ricavo)
            };


            $scope.netti = function() {
                return ($scope.calcolo.ricavo-(($scope.calcolo.abbatt * $scope.calcolo.ricavo)/100))
            };


        });
```

Of course, when I write into a text input, all the the inputs with same ng-model get the same value.

Is there a way in Angular, maybe with IDs, that allows me compiling row by row, without change the others?

Sorry for bad english and thank you!

PS: I can't use ng-repeat.

Comment: You should create a Directive ([Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive))

Comment: Or define a controller for each <tr>. Then each tr would have a different scope

Comment: "all the the inputs with same ng-model get the same value" -> that is what supposed to happen. BTW in your code, the ng-model are all different. Can you clarify what behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm using a while loop to generate "n" rows, so they are all the same. I want my controller works only on the interested row (the row where I'm inputing data). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array for `calcolo` and increase the index for each row in PHP: `ng-model="calcolo[0].abbatt"`,  `ng-model="calcolo[1].abbatt"` etc.

Then in your controller you can loop over the calcolo array.

Answer (score 0):

As @yBrodsky mentioned in the comment, use the controller on each `<tr>`, so you can have different scope for each `<tr>`.

```
<script data-require="angular.js.1.3@*" data-semver="1.5.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"</script>
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $i = 0;
      while($i++ < 5){
    ?>
    <tr data-ng-controller="userController">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="calcolo.ore">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="calcolo.ricavo">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="calcolo.abbatt">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text'  ng-show="calcolo.abbatt" value='{{netti() | currency:"&euro;"}}'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<script>
    angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("userController",
        function($scope) {
            $scope.calcolo = {}; //init

            $scope.fattlord = function() {
                return ($scope.calcolo.ore * $scope.calcolo.ricavo)
            };
            $scope.netti = function() {
                return ($scope.calcolo.ricavo-(($scope.calcolo.abbatt * $scope.calcolo.ricavo)/100))
            };
        }
       );
</script>
</body>
```